# How can I pass an expression to act on a single field in an anonymous type in LINQ

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1, anonymous-types

I have the following Data Transfer Objects defined:

```
Public Class MemberWithAddressesDTO
  Public Property Member_PK As Integer
  Public Property Firstname As String
  Public Property DefaultAddress As AddressDTO
  Public Property Addresses As IQueryable(Of AddressDTO)
End Class

Public Class AddressDTO
  Public Property Address_PK As Integer
  Public Property Address1 As String
  Public Property Address2 As String
End Class
```

I have defined the following expression which maps my entity to my DTO so that I can reuse this in queries (the actual expression is generated by T4 template):

```
Public Shared AsAddressDTO As Expression(Of Func(Of Address, AddressDTO)) =
  Function(ent As Address) New AddressDTO With {.Address_PK = ent.Address_PK, _
                                                 .Address1 = ent.Address1,
                                                 .Address2 = ent.Address2}
```

I can use this expression in a LINQ-to-Entities query to convert lists of Address entities to list of AddressDTOs:

```
Using context As New DbContext
  Dim mem As MemberWithAddressesDTO = 
    context.Members _
      .Where(Function(m) m.Person_PK = 121) _
      .Select(Function(m) New MemberWithAddressesDTO With {
                .Member_PK = m.Person_PK, _
                .Firstname = m.Firstname, _
                .Addresses = ent.Addresses.AsQueryable.Select(AsAddressDTO)}
             ).FirstOrDefault()
End Using
```

This works fine, however if I want to use the same expression to convert a **single field** in member to an AddressDTO in the anonymous type, the only way I can get this to work is to put the field in a single item array, cast to queryable and then call select on that - this seems a bit circuitous and I am wondering if there is a better way:

```
Using context As New DbContext
  Dim mem As MemberWithAddressesDTO = _
    context.Members _
      .Where(Function(m) m.Person_PK = 121) _
      .Select(Function(m) New MemberWithAddressesDTO With {
        .Member_PK = m.Person_PK, _
        .Firstname = m.Firstname, _
        .DefaultAddress = {m.DefaultAddress}.AsQueryable.Select(AsAddressDTO).FirstOrDefault}
      ).FirstOrDefault()
End Using
```

Basically I want to know if there is better syntax to achieve this line in the above:

```
.DefaultAddress = {m.DefaultAddress}.AsQueryable.Select(AsAddressDTO).FirstOrDefault}
```

Note m.DefaultAddress is a single field of type Address - it is not a collection.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do something like this:

```
Using context As New DbContext
  ' Get a delegate to the expression
  Dim func As Func(Of Address, AddressDTO) = AsAddressDTO.Compile()

  Dim mem As MemberWithAddressesDTO = _
    context.Members _
      .Where(Function(m) m.Person_PK = 121) _
      .Select(Function(m) New MemberWithAddressesDTO With {
        .Member_PK = m.Person_PK, _
        .Firstname = m.Firstname, _
        .DefaultAddress = func({m.DefaultAddress})}
      ).FirstOrDefault()
End Using
```

Comment: No that doesn't work. The point here is that AsAddressDTO is an Expression not a Delegate, I need to keep it as an expression so that my query will be evaluated by LINQ-to-Entities and turned into a SQL query against my database, putting a delegate in there will lead to "not supported in LINQ-to-Entities" error... what I am after is someway of doing LINQ expressions against something that isn't IQueryable...

Comment: Hmm - I think my updated answer is also no good, since I'm using a delegate and you say you can't put a delegate in there.  I'm no linq-to-entities expert, but I'm VERY surprised you can't put a delegate there.

Answer (score 0):

NB `Addresses` is still an un-executed query, where as `DefaultAddress` is a real `AddressDTO`.

In any case, because you want to retain the `Expression` you need to keep the `IQueryable`. (Note the `Queryable.Select` has the `Expression` overload that the `Enumerable.Select` does not.)

And the "delayed execution" we're using *is* based upon `IEnumerable`, so a queryable `.SelectOne` *will* still need a `.First` called later.

Thus you need to turn the single value into an enumeration somewhere. And you end up with almost identical code to what you started with:

```
 <Extension> _
 Public Function SelectOne(Of TSource, TResult)(ByVal source As TSource, ByVal selector As Expression(Of Func(Of TSource, TResult))) As IQueryable(Of TResult)
     Return Enumerable.Repeat(source, 1).AsQueryable.Select(selector)
 End Function
```

I did attempt to return an expression that `Invoke` the `selector` with the `source`, but as I mentioned above AFAICT you need an `IEnumerable`.